# Debugging malloc errors in Ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, debugging, malloc

I'm trying to debug errors like the following that I get while running some Ruby scripts:

```
ruby(47333,0x7fff72aee960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f98b6a6e3f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Any idea how I can actually set such a breakpoint and debug?  I want to see whether this is caused by Ruby itself or some extensio..

I'm Using `Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion)` and `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]`.

Comment: That means set a breakpoint using `gdb` or some other C debugger. Using a Ruby and extensions with debugging enabled (i.e. compiled with `-g`) would be helpful.

Comment: @muistooshort if you could go into the steps of how this is done, or provide a link, i think i would likely award the question to you

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Ruby 1.9.2+, install the debugger gem (`gem install debugger`). There are two ways to debug: directly including the `debugger` gem or using the `redbug` binary. Let's pretend we have a toy script, and we want to know why `$blah` is 4 after calling `foo()` (pretend it's an external library).

## Method 1: Including `debugger`

This is setting a breakpoint manually in your code:

```
require 'debugger'

$blah = 3

def foo
  $blah += 1
end

def bar
  $blah += 4
end

foo()
debugger() # opens rdb
bar()

puts $blah
```

Run this as `ruby debug.rb`. This will launch you into a ruby-debug console:

```
% ruby debug.rb
debug.rb:15
bar()
(rdb:1) list
[10, 19] in debug.rb
   10    $blah += 4
   11  end
   12  
   13  foo()
   14  debugger()
=> 15  bar()
   16  
   17  puts $blah
(rdb:1) display $blah
1: $blah = 4
```

## Method 2: Running `rdebug`

Here's our example example script, `debug.rb`:

```
$blah = 3

def foo
  $blah += 1
end

def bar
  $blah += 4
end

foo()
bar()

puts $blah
```

From shell, execute `rdebug debug.rb`. Here's an example session:

```
% rdebug debug.rb
(rdb:1) list 1,20
[1, 20] in /mnt/hgfs/src/stackoverflow/debug.rb
=> 1  $blah = 3
   2  
   3  def foo
   4    $blah += 1
   5  end
   6  
   7  def bar
   8    $blah += 4
   9  end
   10  
   11  foo()
   12  bar()
   13  
   14  puts $blah
(rdb:1) break 12
Breakpoint 1 file /mnt/hgfs/src/stackoverflow/debug.rb, line 12
(rdb:1) display $blah
1: $blah = 
(rdb:1) continue
Breakpoint 1 at /mnt/hgfs/src/stackoverflow/debug.rb:12
1: $blah = 4
/mnt/hgfs/src/stackoverflow/debug.rb:12
bar()
(rdb:1) display $blah
2: $blah = 4
```

The key commands are `break LINE-NUMBER` and `display VARIABLE`. Hope that helps!

## Resources

- [ruby-debug documentation](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html)
- [debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger)

Comment: The problem is that babonk needs to set a breakpoint in a C function (`malloc_error_break`) so that they can backtrack into the interpreter or a C-based extension to figure who is freeing a pointer twice.

Comment: @muistooshort: babonk is running a Ruby script, so I'm assuming the bug is from an external library that uses a C extension. It sounded like setting some breakpoints before the library call would be more useful than debugging someone's C extension. However, if that's desired, [this ruby-talk message](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/18105) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what solved my problem when I saw the OP's message:

I got the message because I had messed with paths, trying to get `rvm` or `gem` to install something, and I managed to really muck up my permissions.  Then I got this same message the OP is reporting. For me, the only thing that did it was to go to Mac OS X's `Disk Utility`, select my volume in the left pane (Macintosh HD), and then click `Repair Disk Permissions`.

After it finished, I was able to successfully open and start up a new terminal window.