# MacOS error for object 0x7f8b8d004c40: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, macos-sierra

I have a problem when I run rails s or rails routes,
most of the time I will get the following error message:

```
ruby(2177,0x7fff96a0b3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8b8d004c40: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have tried all solutions
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)
but it doesn't help, any ideas?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922777/debugging-malloc-errors-in-ruby-on-mac-os-x

Comment: thanks man, but since i have no `Repair Disk Permissions` in Disk Utility, I ran First Aid which i tried before in Recovery Mode, but still it does not work.
is that a random problem?

Comment: even reinstall the macOS(without deleting files) does not work for me, gonna try formatting the whole thing in the weekend if I can't fix it.

Comment: i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478906/ruby-errors-with-os-x-yosemite

Comment: just tried to do it in my free time, but still it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

After I tried clean reinstall MacOS, the error still exist, so the error must be in my code.

But since malloc is a C thing, I took a closer look at the gems I am currently using, and found one of the gem is a C extension.

I removed that gem, and everything is fine, just I have to find a alternative to that gem.